# Seaborn heatmap widths do not match when using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, sum, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to adjust the width of my second subplot (column sum with the binary cmap) to the first one.

So far I only managed to do so by randomly selecting different figsize, but every time I trying to re-use the code on a dataset of different size I alwayse come up with something like the picture below (second heatmap always wider than the first one).

Am I missing something to adjust the second one automatically ?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import seaborn as sns   
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob','Janice','Janice','Fernand','Kevin','Sidhant'], 
                     'tag' : ['enfant','enfant','enfant','femme','femme','jeune','jeune','jeune'],
                   'income': [3, 5, 1,14,8,10,13,17]})
  
# specify font sizes for later:

titlesize= 30
ticklabel = 23
legendlabel = 23

# Generate custom diverging colormaps:

cmap = sns.color_palette("ch:18,-.1,dark=.3",  6)
cmap2 = sns.color_palette("binary",  6)

# Preparing data for the heatmap:

heatmap1_data = pd.pivot_table(test, values='income', 
                                 index=['user'], 
                                 columns='tag')
heatmap1_data = heatmap1_data.reindex(heatmap1_data.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index, axis=1)

# Creating figure:

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(10,15))

# First subplot:

sns.heatmap(heatmap1_data, ax= ax1, cmap=cmap,square=True, linewidths=.5, annot=True, cbar = False,annot_kws={"size": legendlabel} )

# Cosmetic first subplot:

ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labelsize= ticklabel, top = False)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_ylabel('')
ax1.set_xticklabels(heatmap1_data.columns,rotation=90)
ax1.set_yticklabels(heatmap1_data.index,rotation=0)
ax1.set_title("Activités par agence et population vulnérable", size= titlesize, pad=20)

# Second subplot (column sum at the bottom):

sns.heatmap((pd.DataFrame(heatmap1_data.sum(axis=0))).transpose().round(1), ax=ax2, square=True, fmt='g', linewidths=.5, annot=True, cmap=cmap2 , cbar=False, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, annot_kws={"size": legendlabel})
ax2.set_xlabel("Nombre d'activités", size = ticklabel, labelpad = 5)

# More cosmetic:

ax1.set_title("Title", size= titlesize, pad=35)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_ylabel('')
plt.tick_params(labelsize= ticklabel,left=False, bottom=False)
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('#dfe1ec')
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('#dfe1ec')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('#dfe1ec')
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('#dfe1ec')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is using `square=True` in `sns.heatmap`. Since the aspect ratios of the two subplots are wide vs tall, the way that the "squaring" is done is different for each. For the first, it's made thinner, and the second, it's made shorter. It's done this way to fit into the constraints of the your subplot Axes' sizes, which are defined to be equal by default when you call `plt.subplots`.

One way to get around this is to define the aspect ratios of your two Axes to be different and fit the shape of your data. This won't work 100 % of the time but will in most cases. You can use the keyword `gridspec_kw` and define a dictionary with `'height_ratios'` in your call of `plt.subplots`.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(10,15), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[5, 1]})
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to add a second horizontal heatmap below ? # create figure
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(27,17),gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[18, 1]}) brings up the error message : ValueError: Expected the given number of height ratios to match the number of rows of the grid

Comment: Got it, add another 1 in gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[18, 1]}) :)